# Should I use Spring Boot Rest Controller for Command-line app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, console-application

I am trying to create a command-line Java program for reading REST API, but I am not sure about the most proper way to achieve this.

Before proceed, I need to be clarified regarding to the following issue. Could you help me please?

**1.** As a Spring Boot user, I think it is good idea to use Spring Boot for this console app. Is that right? Or is it meaningless to use a Controller or Spring Web for this console app?

**2.** If I should use Spring Boot Console app, do I only need Spring Boot dependency as I do not connect to database(I also need to map json result to my beans, maybe I need Jackson)?

**3.** When I get query parameters from user via console, I think I should pass these parameters to my Controller. Then, pass the request to my service and from service, I will send the API requests to the remote server. Is that a correct scenario? or should I directly pass request from my Controller to the remote API?

Note: I normally use Spring Boot for our web project, but I have no experience for using it in Console app. So, I would be appreciated if experienced users helps me.

Comment: Why would you need a web stack to run a console app? JUst use Spring Boot without the web part.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually  have no idea and trying to find the most proper way for this scenario. At first I thought as you described, but could not be sure. Then I create a Spring Boot app as you suggested.

Comment: @M.Deinum On the other hand, in order to follow best practices, I think I should create a service and manage the rest api request in that service (I will pass the user request from Console to the service): Is that good?

Comment: @M.Deinum Are you there sir?

Comment: What layering and components you need depend on your application. If you can benefit from it do it, if you don't leave it out.